# how can i add parameter to insert command in vb.net code

Tags: vb.net, insert

I have two tables and the form contains a text box so I need to add rows of Table 1 to Table 2 and taking the value in the text box for each row is added to Table 2.

i have insert syntax but it is need to modification:

```
INSERT INTO table2(column3,column4) 
SELECT column1 + @parameter 
FROM table1 
WHERE column2=true
```

table1: column1 column2

table2: column3 column4

Form1: it have textbox1

the full code :

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
Try
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\DellXPS\Desktop\mDB.accdb"

    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table2(column3,column4) SELECT column1 + @parameter FROM table1 WHERE column2=true"

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@parameter",  OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
Finally
    con.Close()
End Try
```

i think the wrong in insert syntax ,, hop to corrected

Comment: i found the right code 

 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table2(column3, column4) SELECT column1, @parameter FROM table1 WHERE column2=true"

that is it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to add parameter with value in command:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter",TextBox1.Text);
```